# Passing member function to Template function

Tags: c++, c++11

Given the following function:

```
template<class F, class... Args>
auto ThreadPool::enqueue(F&& f, Args&&... args) 
    -> std::future<typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type>
{
    using return_type = typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type;

    auto task = std::make_shared< std::packaged_task<return_type()> >(
            std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...)
        );

    std::future<return_type> res = task->get_future();
    return res;
}
```

What's the right way to pass a member function to `ThreadPool::enqueue` as parameter, say the object is:

```
Foo foo
```

and the function is:

```
foo.do_something();
```

I have tried to use `std::bind` and `std::mem_fn` with or without "&" and all failed.

Comment: Try `pool.enqueue([foo]() { foo.do_something(); });`

Comment: Did you try: pool.enqueue([foo]{foo.do_something();}) ?

Comment: Instead of saying you "tried bind and mem_fun", show us the code you tried.

Comment: For a non-overloaded non-template function you can also use `pool.enqueue(&Foo::do_something, &foo, other_args_to_do_something...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what @IgorTandetnik has mentioned in the comments, you can also use `std::bind` with `std::mem_fn` to pass a member function to your method:

```
struct Foo
{
   void do_something() {}
   void do_something_else(int x, int y, std::string str) {}
};

int main()
{
   Foo foo;
   ThreadPool pool;

   auto func_sth = std::bind(std::mem_fn(&Foo::do_something), foo);
   auto func_sth_else = std::bind(std::mem_fn(&Foo::do_something_else), foo, 10 , 11, "hi");

   pool.enqueue(func_sth);
   pool.enqueue(func_sth_else);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the correct syntax if do_something take parameters, say two ints?

Comment: @BulGali I updated the answer for a function with some parameters.

Comment: For some reason I get: /functional:467:70: error: no matching function for call to 'std::tuple<AlgoTravel*, std::__cxx11::basic_string...>. Any idea why that might happen? Is there a special syntax if the parameters are passed by reference? say "std::string &str"?

Comment: @BulGali If you are going to pass one parameter (e.g. `str`) by reference, then pass the parameter with `std::ref(str)`.  For const-reference parameters, you can use `std::cref()` instead.